# How to apply TextTrimming CharacterEllipsis to text in TextBlock

Tags: button, uwp

I have text block and a button . They are attached in a grid in consecutive colums. There CharacterEllipsis not worked in text block. Code is given below. Please give an idea on how to do this.

Comment: <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        
                                                            <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind Name}" FontSize="20" Padding="10" />
                                                        </Border>
                                                                </StackPanel>

Answer (score 0):

The `TextTrimming` trigger condition is that the length of the current Text exceeds the size of the `TextBlock`. From that, for `TextTrimming` to take effect, you can do this in the following two ways:

1. Set the `Width` of the `TextBlock`:

```xml
<TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Width="100" Text="{x:Bind Name}" .../>
```

If the width of the `TextBlock` parent container is fixed and does not need to change with the content size, you can explicitly set `TextBlock.Width`.

2. Change container type to `Grid`:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!--First column element-->

    <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind Name}" .../>
</Grid>
```

`Grid` and `StackPanel` are different. Although its width is also related to content, you can limit the width of a column of the Grid to not exceed the parent container by setting `<ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />`, which also achieves the purpose of setting the width in disguise.

This method is more flexible and suitable for situations where the width of the container is uncertain.

Best regards.